# Does Quarkus implementation gRPC service supports using PKCS #12 certificates for SSL?

Tags: ssl, grpc, grpc-java, pkcs#12

*I found this link which probably hints that it is not possible (https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-cpp/issues/5116). In case, some one figured out the secret sauce. Do share.*

I am hosting gRPC service on Quarkus. Any idea if Quarkus gRPC supports pkcs#12 certificates? It certainly works fine with pkcs#8.

Comment: gRPC is an application protocol which has a variety of implementations. PKCS#12 is a container format for storing cryptographic keys and certificates. Could gRPC could be used together with certificates and keys - yes. Can these certificates and keys be used on the server side and client side (i.e. mTLS) - yes. Is it possible to provide the certificates and keys in PKCS#12 format (compared to PEM or DER format) - this depends on your specific implementation, but this is not what you are asking. Can PKCS#12 be converted to PEM or DER - yes.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That's not what am asking but I should be. Theoretically, it should just work, but it didn't. Thanks for the pointer though. I should go check the gRPC service implementation - in my case Quarkus. If they support it or not. I shall edit my question as well

Comment: *" it should just work,"* - why? If it supports PEM (and looks like it does) you can easily convert from PKCS#12 to PEM. It's pretty common that TLS is supported with PEM but not with PKCS#12. Maybe you need to adjust your expectations instead. *" It certainly works fine with pkcs#8."* - this is totally unrelated. Just because it supports one standard for private keys (which is also used for PEM files) does not mean that it supports every other standard starting with PKCS in the name.

Comment: Unfortunately, the expectations come from SecOps :(
Need to make it work with pkcs#12 certs. Thanks again for your thoughts. I was probably too frustrated to express the problem correctly.